# Мародер или мародёр

Tags: орфография, е-или-ё

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно, «мародер» или «мародёр»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, *марод**ё**р.* Это слово из французского, "maraudeur", оно так и произносится ([произношение](https://forvo.com/word/maraudeur/#fr)), в отличие от слов, оканчивающихся на -aire и -ier, например, "диспансе́р" и "гренадер" соответственно. Хотя ближе к французскому произношению было бы "гренадьер" (ещё точнее "грёнадье"). А "диспансер" так и произносится за исключением того, что Н носовое, а Р французское.

Answer (score 2):

**мародёр**
Существительное, одушевлённое, мужской род; корень: *-мародёр-* [Тихонов, 1996].
(*печатный вариант*: А. Н. Тихонов. Словообразовательный словарь русского языка в двух томах, том I, 1990)

**мародёр**
*печатный вариант*: Современный словарь иностранных слов, 1992

**мародёр**
*печатные* орфографические словари:
проф. Д. Н. Ушаков, 1938
под. ред. С. И. Ожегова и А. Б. Шапиро, 1957
В. В. Бурцева, 2003

Однокоренные слова: мародёрка, мародёрство, мародёрствовать, мародёрский, мародёрничать (редко встречаются по-мародёрски, мародёрный).